# Generic Array Creating When I'm Not Using Generics

Tags: java, generics

When trying to implement Fibonacci Heap in Java I'm getting a generic array creation error even though I'm not using generics.

```
private void consolidate() {
    Node[] degrees = new Node[45];
}
```

The `Node` class is this:

```
private class Node {

    public E val;
    public Node left, right, child;
    public int degree;
    public boolean mark;

    public Node(E _val) {
        val = _val;
    }

    public void insert(Node newNode) {
        if(left == this) {
            left = newNode;
            right = newNode;
            left.right = this;
            left.left = this;
        } else {
            Node temp = left;
            left = newNode;
            left.right = this;
            left.left = temp;
            temp.right = left;
        }
    }

    public void unlink() {
        left.right = right;
        right.left = left;

        if(child != null) {
            Node dummy = child;

            do {
                left.insert(dummy);
                dummy = dummy.left;
            } while(dummy != child);
        }
    }

}
```

I thought that maybe this part was causing the error:

```
public E val;
```

and

```
    public Node(E _val) {
        val = _val;
    }
```

however I changed both of them to `Object`, and it still didn't work. If it helps, `E` extends `Comparable<E>`.

```
public class FibonacciHeap<E extends Comparable<E>>
```

Comment: I'm guessing `Node` is an inner class of `FibonacciHeap`.  But an inner class of a generic is effectively a generic, because it's within the scope of the type parameter.  You knew this, because you used `E` within the `Node` class.

Comment: How do you suggest I fix this?

Comment: I'd use an `ArrayList` instead of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `FibonacciHeap` is generic actually, so its inner private class `Node` is generic too as mentioned in the first comment.

If you think your Node class should not be generic, you can either make it inner static class using `Object val`:

```
public class FibonacciHeap<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    private static class Node {
        Object val;
        // ...
    }
}
```

or move its definition outside `FibonacciHeap`:

```
public class FibonacciHeap<E extends Comparable<E>> {

}

private class Node {
    Object val;
    // ...
}
```

There's also an option to remove generic from `FibonacciHeap` too.